# Format decimal value

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I had this, which works as far as it goes:

```
worksheet.write(row, column, value)
```

Then I wanted to make the value display in red, so I did this:

```
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
worksheet.write_rich_string(row,column, str(value), red)
```

This works, but the problem is that value is a `decimal`, and it has to be cast to a string for it to work with `write_rich_string()`
Is there a way to format the value and have it remain a decimal?
In Excel, I would to Conditional Formatting on the entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`write_number()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-number) also accepts a cell format:

```
red = workbook.add_format({'color': 'red'})
worksheet.write_number(1, 1, 10.24, red)
```